# Showing error message on MEAN website

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am quite new to MEAN and I am learning a lot. At the moment I am trying to show an error message on my page when an user is not allowed into the website. The page contains a button which redirects you to the steam login. After you login the steam API sends your steamid which I will then check in the mongodb database:

```
app.get('/auth/steam/return',
    passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/' }),https://stackoverflow.com/users/5333805/luud-van-keulen
    function(req, res) {
        UserModel.findOne({ steamid : req.user.id }, function (err, user) {
            if(!user) {
                console.log('does not exist');
                //Probably have to set the error message here
            } else {
                req.session.userid = req.user.id; //Setting the session
            }
        });

        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

The only thing that I can't get working is how to show a message when the user is not allowed (he is not in the database). I want to use AngularJS for the HTML (so no Jade).

I do know that I have to set a variable somewhere in the response header and then with AngularJS I need to check if this variable exists or not. When It exist it should show the div which contains the error message.

The problem is that I can't use res.render because I need to redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using express-flash.

Answer (score 0):

So in the block where user is not found, you should have something like:

```
res.status(401).send("Login failed.");
```

And then on the client side you can check the response status and display the mesage.

Edit: if you need help on the client side as well, please provide your client code.

Comment: I always thought those status messages where for HTTP messages. Is it a good practice to use them to show login messages?

Comment: It's a message you show a user if they fail to login. 401 is the unauthorized status and you should definitely send it, but the message is optional. You can add client side logic that will show a 'Login Failed' message if the server returns 401.

Comment: In fact, I'd rather go with sending the message from the server, since the server knows exactly what failed (i. e. user not found, password incorrect), whereas if you're showing a message based on the 401 status, it can only be a generic message.

Comment: I want to show it under the login button. Not sure if that's possible with 401.

Comment: Of course it's possible - can we look at the code that sends the auth request? You handle the response and if it's a 401 you take the message and show it wherever you want.

Comment: The auth request goes through passport which redirects the user to the steam login page. Then after the user logs in he gets redirected to the callback url. In this page I want to either show him the message or redirect him to the authorized page.